# Extremely long loops in Python seem to be timing out

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I am running into a strange problem that when running extremely long loops / computations in Python, the loop seems to terminate but no result is computed. Moreover, the interpreter seems to crash and does not support further computation.

Environment: Python 2.7 (Enthought Canopy) with IPython interpreter.

For example, consider the dummy function:

```
>>> def myfunc(n):
       t = 0;
       for i in xrange(n):
           t += i
       return t
>>> myfunc(100000000)
Out[7]: 4999999950000000L
>>> myfunc(10e10L)   
##---- runs for a minute with no response / return-value and then the prompt shows.----
>>>
>>> myfunc(100)
---- no response --- 
>>> print 'hello'
---- no response --- 
>>>
```

While I expect large loops to overflow - and maybe throw an error, I am not sure why the function call returns without any result. Is this behavior expected ?

Comment: are you saying myfunc(100) is returning nothing? You are saying you see no result but you have posted `Out[7]: 4999999950000000L` so you have a result. It is a bit unclear what exactly you are asking

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue, even with an extra zero in the argument. It takes about as long as expected, and returns the expected result.

Comment: your example works for me. Could it be, you're using `range` and get some memory issues?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Obviously, the 2nd call gives no result. And the third one, with just 100, doesn't as well.

Comment: @glglgl, I don't think there is anything obvious about the question at all  "Moreover, the interpreter effectively stops working - i.e. it doesn't do any other computation", how would the interpreter do anything else when it is already running a function?

Comment: As the text already says, "This now runs for about a minute and then returns with no result." This means that after a minute, it is possible to run the next function...

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my mail. I intended the following code sequence: